# Problem in using udhcp and dnsmasq on same machine

Tags: networking, wifi, ethernet, port-forwarding

I am using my Raspberry Pi for configuring both as an wifi hostpot and wired router not at same time. I have written separate bash script file (.sh file) for creating configuration files for wifi and wired router.
I am using udhcp and dnsmasq for configuring Rpi as wifi hotspot. Tutorial on [elinux](http://elinux.org/RPI-Wireless-Hotspot).

When i run wifi.sh file with `sudo ./wifi.sh` following files are written successfully

```
hostapd
hostapd.conf
udhcpd
udhcpd.conf
sysctl.conf
interfaces
```

and the following command will execute

```
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT

sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat"

service hostapd start
service udhcpd start

update-rc.d hostapd enable
update-rc.d udhcpd enable
```

Similarly for `sudo ethernet.sh` following files and command will execute. I am using dnsmasq for this. [tutorial](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By3r0jR6h8ekYnpPak9kV1NsQkU/view)

```
dnsmasq.conf
sysctl.conf
interfaces


iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE  

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT  
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT  

sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat"
```

But when i first switch from wifi to ethernet it works. But when again switch from ethernet to wifi, hotspot generating but i can't connect my device.

When i searched about it, some are saying it is because of udhcpd server.

But both script work standalone.

What will be the reason?